# how to calculate distance in sub pixel mapping from Atkinson's paper?

Tags: r, classification

Condition from atkindon's paper http://info.asprs.org/publications/pers/2005journal/july/2005_july_839-846.pdf

for every sub-pixel the attractiveness Ai of a pixel
i is predicted as a distance-weighted function of its j  1,2,
. . . , J neighbors:

```
A(i)= sum (j=1 to J) { lambda(i,j)*z(x(j))}
```

where z(x(j)) is the (binary) class of the jth pixel at location x(j),
and lambda(i,j) is a distance-dependent weight predicted as:

```
lambda(i,j)= exp(-h(i,j)/a)
```

where h(i,j) is the distance between the location x(i) of pixel i
for which the attractiveness is desired, the location x(j) of a
neighboring pixel j, and "a" is the non-linear parameter of the
exponential model.

**My question is how to calculate h(i,j) and what is going to be the input for x(i) and x(j)**, the things I know as input are the class labels of the subpixels but how to calculate distance using them.

As in my case x(i) can be 1 as class label and x(j) can be 2. till now I am able to randomly fill the subpixel classes in a finer grid.

Comment: You seem to be asking how to compute distances between any two neighboring pixels in a grid. Is that really what you want to know? If so, what is problematic about the calculation? Does it lie in the format of the inputs? The software you are using? Something else?

Comment: Yes, the problem lies with the formats of the input...I am trying to code the algorithm given in that paper, I was able to get till the filling of subpixels with the fraction of land cover classes generated using linear spectral unmixing, but they are filled randomly, so to arrange them based on spatial dependency measure i want to use pixel swapping algorithm, so here am unable to know how to calculate the lambda through which I can calculate sub pixel attractiveness.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.